# What is the recommended way to generate API tokens using Laravel framework?

Tags: authentication, web-application, php, mobile, api

I'm a newbie in terms of security, but I need a suggestion to make sure the connection between an API and mobile apps is secure. I'm currently using the Laravel framework. Based on its [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#hashing-tokens):

> When using hashed API tokens, you should not generate your API tokens during user registration.

The questions are:

1. When should the token being generated if it's not during registration?
2. Is the token supposed to be generated on every login with specified expiration time?

Thank you!

Comment: In the documentation that you mentioned, the recommendation is to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport), "which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application". Have you checked this already?

Comment: The [Laravel Passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#configuration) explains when and how an API token is generated, and that it's default lifetime is 1 year.

Comment: As you said, Laravel Passport uses OAuth 2.0 which is the best for inter-application Authentication (and Authorization, I think...) but in this case, the API server only serve one mobile app (which supports Android and iOS). That's the reason why I prefer more simple approach but keep it secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel use php concepts and libraries.

so if we install any jwt libraries we can find out all of them use a configuration file for set expire date for jwt tokens ( for example 7 days. ) [see this article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-time-expire-for-jwt?page=1)

you as developer can configure it e.g 30 s. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41268134/308578

if you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbsmsi7l3r4) i definitely sure ,you can found out more about jwt token libraries functionality and their concepts . but this video about nodejs but concept is the same ....

any time to want you can refresh or generate tokens and pass it to your clients.

i think after this video you can understand more all you want

enjoy